# ReactJS - How to change the date format from an input field?

Tags: reactjs, date, events, input, formatting

In react app, I am using an array like,

```
const result = [
  {firstname: "Shruthi", lastname: "R", phone: "1234567890", birthday: "24/05/1991"},
  {firstname: "Maanya", lastname: "C", phone: "8882334324", birthday: "19/07/1990"},
  {firstname: "Chethan", lastname: "Kumar", phone: "7888382222", birthday: "24/05/1995"}
];
```

Date input field is,

```
<input type="date" onChange={props.handleOnChange} />

handleOnChange = (e) => {
  const date = e.target.value; // getting different format here
  console.log(date);
}
```

Based on the above, date input field and the birthday field in array list (`result`) contains `dd/mm/yyyy` format but in `handleOnChange` function I am getting it in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

How can I change the date format to `dd/mm/yyyy` ?

Comment: Just use `.split('-')` to chop it up and stitch it together in the right order with `.join('/')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
let today  = new Date("2020-11-18");
today.toLocaleDateString("en-US"); // 11/18/2020
today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB"); // 18/11/2020
today.toLocaleDateString("bn-IN"); // ১৮/১১/২০২০
```

or you can use moment

```
moment(moment('2020-11-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a object called **Intl.DateTimeFormat**  that enable language-sensitive date and time formatting in JavaScript. You can use this as follow and do changes you want

> console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: Good choice. One small thing, if they're getting a **string** in the `handleOnChange` function, then they'll need to convert it to a date first: `new Date(date)`